# CakePHP dompdf image crash

Tags: image, cakephp, crash, dompdf

Whenever I try to insert an image into a PDF, the whole PDF file crashes. (Google Chrome says, 'Failed to load PDF document', and the network response is empty.)

I am using the dompdf plugin for cakephp, and the error is definitely not due to dompdf not finding the images. When the source attribute points to a non-existing image, it just shows a square rectangle. When, on the other hand, the path is correct, or I provide the source using the 'data:…;base64,…' notation, the whole PDF crashes.

I have increased the maximum resolution to 300dpi in Config/dompdf.php , but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does not look like a CakePHP issue to me.

Comment: It needn't be, but it's important to point out that I am using the CakePHP plugin for dompdf.

Comment: please point out which plugin you are using.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why, but it works now. I did not do absolutely anything in the meantime except, possibly, shutting down the computer.